# Move a file inside a mercurial forest from one repo to another?

Tags: mercurial

Is there an `hg` command to move a file within a forest from one repo to another?
That is, a command, similar to what `hg mv` does for a single repository?
Or do I have to delete the file in one repo and create a copy in the another repo?

Answer (score 1):

There are no commands to move files between repositories, so yes, copy and commit the file in the other repo and delete from the original.

Comment: So, no way to keep history?

Comment: There is a `convert` extension that you could convert a repository to one containing only the history of a select set of files, then `hg pull -f` from that repo into the target repo.  The target repo would contain two different history lines that could then be merged.  I've done this to add a project in one repo to a set of projects in another repo.  If interested I could put together an example.